# What is the use of set and get methods for path and domain when this are the parts of response header?

Tags: servlets, cookies

my actual question is....how to read domain,path,comment from the request.getHeader("Cookie") if all these are part of the header instead of  using built in methods set and get method.

```
 Cookie c=new Cookie("lastCookie","tired");// this is my setCookieFile.java
 c.setMaxAge(60);
 c.setPath("/");
 c.setDomain("localhost");
 c.setComment("Complicated");     
 response.addCookie(c);

 Cookie c[]=request.getCookies();   //this is getCookieFile.java  
  for (Cookie cookie : c) {
        out.println("Name="+cookie.getName());
        out.println("Path="+cookie.getPath());
        out.println("Domain="+cookie.getDomain());
        out.println("Comment="+cookie.getComment());
        out.println("Values="+cookie.getValue());

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, designers of the servlet API chose to use the same object to represent a cookie that you add to a response (and which contains a path, domain, etc.), and a cookie that you get from a request, and which does'nt contain anything other than a name and a value, because everything else is kept inside the browser. So, you can't access the path or domain of a cookie in a request.

Comment: thanks JB. so can we read those information using request.getHeader("Cookie")..actually it returns a string with all those attributes.

Comment: No. The only things sent by the browser are the cookie name and its value: `Cookie:somename=somevalue`